# Allow external user to create Account records from public community page

Tags: community, community-builder, site.com

I have a requirement where external guest users can create Account records from a publicly available community URL. I have created an Aura component with Apex class. In general the aura form is creating accounts successfully.
The URL is opening successfully for external users, however upon clicking the create button no record is getting created. In the error handling I am getting the response as ERROR.
Is there any object privilege that I am missing out. Please provide any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

External Guest Users have the access defined in the Guest User Profile for that Experience Cloud site. If you are receiving an error due to permissions, you should confirm that the Profile is configured with Create access on the Account object.

These Help Articles should help:

- [Give Guest Users Access to Create Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_give_guest_users_access_to_create_records.htm)
- [Configure the Guest User Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_config_guest_user_profile.htm&type=5)